# EditorFor field clear button with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button

having Html code :

```
<div class="form-group has-feedback">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Name" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <span class="form-control-clear glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

trying to make clear button with javascript :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.form-control-clear').on("click", function () {
        $(this).val('')
    });
});
```

but not working

Comment: add condition and try .. like this `if ($(this).val() !== " ")
        $(this).val(" ")`

Comment: are you sure the editor is an `input`? can you post the rendered html?

Comment: that was a mistake when i was trying to specify the input type..
any way I edited it